# Is there a way to prevent (bootstrap five) each tab pane from using the same scroll position? Each tab in syncronized with the others scroll position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

Each tab in bootstrap 5's tab pane uses the same scroll position. if i switch from tab #1 and go to tab #2, they both are at the same scroll position. it does not save each tab panes specific location.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">

</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="different" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="different-tab">

</div>

if i scroll to the bottom of the first tab, the second one will be at the bottom when i go to it. ive tried to capture the y position but i cant seem to figure out how to capture a tab panes scroll position.
```

Comment: not sure why this took me so long to figure out sorry for wasting ur server space daddy stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. make vars for each tab scroll value
2. create activeTab var with the tab thats present on page load
3. add each html tab element with a function that changed the activeTab value and auto scrolls
4. make on scroll event that checks which tab is active and changes scroll value for corresponding var

   var home = 0
   var collection = 0

   activeTab = "home"

   function changeScrollHomeTab(tav){
   activeTab = tav

   ```
    if(activeTab === "home"){
        window.scrollTo(0, home);
    } else if(activeTab === "collection"){
        window.scrollTo(0, collection);
    }
   ```

   }

   window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
   if(activeTab === "home"){
   home = $(window).scrollTop()
   } else if(activeTab === "collection"){
   collection = $(window).scrollTop()
   }
   })

## HTML

```
<div "changeScrollHomeTab('collection')" class="tab-pane fade" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">

</div>

<div onclick="changeScrollHomeTab('collection')" class="tab-pane fade" id="collection"    role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="different-tab">

</div>
```